# GTM in next.sj version 12.3

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, pagespeed, lighthouse

[image: here is the screenshot of unused JS]I have implemented GTM in Next.js (12.3.0) in  _app.tsx file using Next js Script tag and in _document.tsx body tag.

````
    _app.tsx





         ```
    import Script from "next/script";
       <Script
    id="gtag-base"
    strategy="afterInteractive"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GTM_KEY}');
      `,
    }}
  />
            ```





          _docement.tsx 




       ```
        <body>
       <noscript>
      <iframe
               src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?               id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GTM_KEY}`}
        height="0"
        width="0"
        style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden" }}
      />
    </noscript>
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
  </body>

        ```
````

Now  these scripts should be preloaded and on preload of website some GTM events are called and report is generated. Everyting is working fine according to my requirement but due to this performance of site is decreased and reduce unused JS is "1.48s"

Is their any way I can reduce unused JS  to zero ? only GTM code is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know broi don't know bro

Comment: What is this answer? What are you trying to say ? Flagged